# AngularJS $http post to PHP page

Tags: php, angularjs

Finally got this working a $http POST after days of trying to find an answer. Would like to know why I have had to use two different sets of PHP code for two AngularJS $http POST requests.
This  are my AngularJS $http POST requests:

```html
ContactsControllers.factory('messageFactory', ['$http', function($http){
 return {
  sendMessage: function(message,contactIdArray){
   return $http.post('/php/sendMessage.php', {message:message,contactIdArray:contactIdArray});
   }
  };
}]);

ContactsControllers.factory('messagesFactory', ['$http', function($http){
 return {
  getContactMessages: function(contactid){
   var config = {
    params: {
     contactid: contactid
    } 
   };
   return $http.post('/php/getMessages.php',null,config);
  }
 };
}]);
```

and my two PHP code sets:

```html
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data, TRUE);
$thisMessage = $data['message'];
$contactIdArray = $data['contactIdArray'];
```

```html
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")
{
 if(isset($_GET["contactid"]))
 {
  $contactid = json_decode($_GET["contactid"]);
 }
 else{
  $result = "no contact id";
 }
 echo json_encode($contactid);
}
```

If someone could tell me why I could not just use the first sets of angularJS and PHP code for my 'messagesFactory' $http POST request, it will help me understand this a bit better.
Like I said after a couple of days of trying out different code I found this http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/forms/formsubmission/ which I finally got working.

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents("php://input")` only gives access to POST data. So you can't use it to get access to query string data (GET) and incidentally it doesn't allow access to POST data if you've included `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form either.

The reason your first php script works is because the data you are asking for is POST variables.

The reason your first php script does not work for your second request where the data is in the url is that `file_get_contents("php://input")` can't access GET data.

The solutions you could use are to implement a true GET request instead of POST from $http, to send all data as POST not GET using $http, or to do as you have and catch the data using a different method in your php script.